# iOS6 iPad does the number of running apps affect memory warnings frequency?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, ios6, profiling

I'm building my app on a development device that does not have too many apps running at the same time. I'm expecting my customers to run the app with any number of other apps open. To ensure my app wont crash due to memory issues, I would like to test my app under expected operating conditions.

This poses a question - **does the number of other apps visible in the double tap home button bar affects the memory usage of the device?** In other words, if I open every app on the device, then start my app, am I more likely to receive memory warnings than if I have all other apps closed?

I remember hearing a WWDC presentation that mentioned that for some apps that use <8mb of memory, their memory gets written to disk while the app is minimized, not sure what this changes.

Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: "does the number of other apps visible in the double tap home button bar affects the memory usage of the device?". No. The double-tap bar is just a history of recent apps. Some of them may still be in memory, others not. When low on memory, iOS will terminate the most memory-hungry apps first. All you can do is reduce your footprint as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the number of other apps visible in the double tap home button
>   bar affects the memory usage of the device?

No. The multi-tasking bar is just a history of recent apps. Some of them may still be in memory, others not. There is no way for you to know just by looking at it.

When low on memory, iOS will terminate the most memory-hungry background apps first. If your app allocates a lot of memory in a short period of time, it can happen that iOS isn't able to reclaim memory fast enough and will terminate your app immediately.

All you can do is reduce your footprint as much as possible, and try not to allocate huge buffers in one go.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes I think the number of opened apps affects the way your app
>   receives memory warning. Closing all the apps running in the
>   background or restarting the device can decrease the memory warning
>   messages sent to your app (you can see this effect by using instruments).
>
> Advise:
>  
>   When you receive memory warning try to do the following:
>   - Stop timers and other periodic tasks.
>   - Stop any running metadata queries.
>   - Do not initiate any new tasks.
>   - Pause movie playback (except when playing back over AirPlay).
>   - Enter into a pause state if your app is a game.
>   - Throttle back OpenGL ES frame rates.
>   - Suspend any dispatch queues or operation queues executing non-critical code. (You can continue processing network requests and other time-sensitive background tasks while inactive.)

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that apple really does not like it if you tell users to kill other apps. I think its in the App Store review guidelines, and an app may get rejected for suggesting this.

Comment: Well, maybe you are right, but i have one app asks for closing apps in the background every time it gets memory warnings and i downloaded it from the app store (FileApp pro). From my experience in games development apps in the background affect the apps performance especially VOIP apps. I will find out if you are right. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note. I found out that having other apps open does affect real memory allocation. **Profiling the app with "activity monitor" lets you see which apps are currently loaded in memory and how much they use**. Assuming the device has 512mb, you have 512 - (what's open) to use, and iOS may kill some apps to free up memory for your app.